# Break Golang Infinite Loop

Tags: json, loops, go

I was working on a function as follows:

```
func extractKeyValuePairs(taskFilePathList []string) []KeyValue {
    keyValueList := []KeyValue{}
    log.Printf("%v", taskFilePathList)
    for _, fileName := range taskFilePathList {
        file, err := os.Open(fileName)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        dec := json.NewDecoder(file)
        for {
            var kv KeyValue
            err := dec.Decode(&kv)
            if err != nil {
                file.Close()
                break
            }
            keyValueList = append(keyValueList, kv)
        }
    }
    return keyValueList
}
```

However, when this function is run, it never return. I put print statement inside these loops, and it turns out that the function will decode all of the kv pairs inside all of the files, and append it into `keyValueList`, but the loop just never exits. Could anyone provide some clue about why it never returns?

UPDATE: I found out that it is not this function that keeps the program hanging, asking for admin's help to delete it as the function I provided does not have any problem.

Comment: "I wasn't able to shrink the program into smaller reproducible snippet" - what issue did you encounter when attempting to produce an example? ([your previous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77285013/11810946), almost identical, question was closed because the issue was not reproducible). Its unlikely that many users will be keen to download/run a large amount of code from an untrusted repo (and quite likely that you will find the issue whilst attempting to create an example).

Answer (score 2):

when your'e using json decoder you should check return value of **dec.More()** as [example](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Decoder.Decode), so you should change infinite loop to this:

```
func extractKeyValuePairs(taskFilePathList []string) []KeyValue {
    keyValueList := []KeyValue{}
    log.Printf("%v", taskFilePathList)
    for _, fileName := range taskFilePathList {
        file, err := os.Open(fileName)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        dec := json.NewDecoder(file)
        for dec.More() {
            var kv KeyValue
            err := dec.Decode(&kv)
            if err != nil {
                file.Close()
                break
            }
            keyValueList = append(keyValueList, kv)
        }
    }
    return keyValueList
}
```